# back button showing in wrong side

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

in my ionic 2 project when i add back button . it's perfect in IOS but in android it showing in right side which is wrong.

here is my code

```
<ion-header><ion-toolbar>
 <ion-buttons start>
    <button ion-button clear large navPop>
      <ion-icon class="icon-back back"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
<ion-title>PageName</ion-title></ion-toolbar></ion-header>
```

here is my nav 
[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUvT5.png)

Comment: I've added some more info to the answer, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you can see [in this answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/nav-bar-with-button-on-left-side/51963/5):

> Start and End follow the UI pattern for the platform
>
> So `<ion-buttons start>` would be on the left for ios and be the first
>   button on the right for android.
>
> `<ion-buttons end>` would be on the right for ios and the last button
>   on the right for android.
>
> Left/right are provide as a way to over ride that.

So if you want to place that icon in the left, instead of `start` use the `left` attribute:

```
<ion-header><ion-toolbar>
 <ion-buttons left>
    <button ion-button clear large navPop>
      <ion-icon class="icon-back back"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
<ion-title>PageName</ion-title></ion-toolbar></ion-header>
```